# How to add options in Attribute in magento 1.9 programmatically?

Tags: attributes, attribute-options

I want to add options in an attributes programmatically like in Size attribute i want S,M,L,XL as an option . My code is creating attribute but i want options with attributes.

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

// Attribute basic data
$attributeName = 'Sizes'; // Name of the attribute
$attributeCode = 'Sizes'; // Code of the attribute
//$attributeGroup = 'Custom Group'; // Group to add the attribute to
// Attribute configuration data
$data = array(
'type' => 'varchar', // Attribute type
'input' => 'select', // Input type
'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL, // Attribute scope
'required' => true, // Is this attribute required?
'user_defined' => false,
'searchable' => false,
'filterable' => false,
'comparable' => false,
'visible_on_front' => false,
'unique' => false,
'used_in_product_listing' => true,
// Adding basic data
'label' => $attributeName,
);

$data['value']['any_option_name'][0] = 'S';

// Installer code to create attribute with new installer class (can be used in non-EAV setup)
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode, $data);

// Notice: Default Attribute Set have ID 4

// Add the attribute to the all attribute proper sets and proper groups:
$entity = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY;
$attributeSetIds = $installer->getAllAttributeSetIds($entity);
foreach($attributeSetIds as $attributeSetId)
{
$installer->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSetId, $attributeCode);
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own source model class such as following:

> Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno

Then add in your $data array the line:

> 'source' => 'model URI here'

Reinstall attribute. In eav_attribute table the source model will be changed for  "sizes" attribute.

P.S. About model URI you can read [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html)